# Como gerar um serial key que contenha um prefixo nos primeiros 5 caracteres?

Tags: php

Eu tenho um *script* em PHP que gera um "*serial key*", mas preciso que esse script gere esse "*serial key*" com um padrão no inicio, como se fosse um prefixo.

O código que já tenho é:

```
<?php
$chars = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
$serial = '';
$max = count($chars)-1;
for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
    $serial .= (!($i % 5) && $i ? '-' : '').$chars[rand(0, $max)];
}
echo $serial;
?>
```

Que gera um serial assim:

- "HJMW0-5RRXT-CS853-BD888"

Quero que os 5 primeiros caracteres (o primeiro conjunto antes do " - ") de todos os seriais gerados sejam iguais e os outros sejam apenas números, sem letras, dessa maneira:

- "XYAMN-97354-81037-01936"
- "XYAMN-75903-81938-01936"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas o prefixo do seu serial, será um texto fixo que você mesmo irá escolher?? Se for você pode fazer uma alteração bem simples no seu código, que é tirar todas as letras do array, e diminuir a contagem do for de 20 para 15 digitos, e colocar o seu texto de prefixo manualmente, dessa forma:

```
$chars = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$serial = '';
$max = count($chars)-1;
for($i=0;$i<15;$i++){
    $serial .= (!($i % 5) && $i ? '-' : '').$chars[rand(0, $max)];
}
echo 'XYAMN-'.$serial;
```

Agora se você quer que o prefixo seja de letras aleatórias, você pode separar em 2 array, um para números e outro para letras, e criar 2 `for`. Mas eu sugeria uma forma simplificada sem arrays utilizando a função `chr` do php, dessa forma:

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
    $prefixo .= strtoupper(chr(rand(97, 122))); //97 é o codigo ascii para 'a' e 122 para z
}

for($i=0; $i<15; $i++){
    $serial .= (!($i % 5) && $i ? '-' : '').rand(0, 9);
}
echo $prefixo.'-'.$serial;
```

E se você criar funções e classes para deixar seu gerador de serial muito mais dinâmico. Como por exemplo fazer um modificador para o separador de dígitos, utilizar um único for para as duas situações, e etc. Por exemplo:

```
function Serial($tipo = '', $qtdigitos = 5, $qtdbaterias = 4, $separador = '-') {
    $qtdtotal = $qtdbaterias * $qtdigitos;
    $letrasnumeros = array_merge(range(0,9), range('A', 'Z')); // Cria um array de letras e numeros de forma simplificada

    for($i=0; $i < $qtdtotal; $i++){

        if ($tipo == 'numeros') { $digito = rand(0, 9); } 
        else if($tipo == 'letras') { $digito = chr(rand(65, 90)); }   //65 é o codigo ascii para 'A' e 90 para 'Z'
        else { $digito = $letrasnumeros[rand(0, count($letrasnumeros) - 1)]; }

        $serial .= (!($i % $qtdigitos) && $i ? $separador : '').$digito;
    }
  return $serial;
}
```

E ai você pode utilizar a função de várias formas:

```
// Retorna serial com letras e numeros, 
// Ex: RQ4BD-1NSBA-PXUD9-DOKS6
echo Serial(); 

// Retorna serial só com números, 
// Ex: 07295-31860-33824-63832
echo Serial('numeros'); 

// Retorna serial só com letras, 
// Ex: CDMIC-AXLET-BRMGW-QUVWL
echo Serial('letras'); 

// Retorna serial só com números mas quantidade diferente de caracteres, 
// Ex: 339-671-633-081-731-120
echo Serial('numeros', 3, 6); 

// Utilizar separadores diferentes,
// Ex: 2CQHJ.SF1E6.D5SOG.UA10K
echo Serial('aleatorio', 5, 4, '.');

// Juntar formas e quantidades diferentes,
// Ex: AMQGUUY-82468-32482-84190
echo Serial('letras', 7, 1).'-'.Serial('numeros', 5, 3);

// Juntar texto fixo com serial
// Ex: XYAMN-16697-17479-56095
echo 'XYAMN-'.Serial('numeros', 5, 3);
```

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 3):

Separe em duas funções como no código abaixo:

```
function prefixo(){
    $chars = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
    $prefixo = '';
    $max = count($chars)-1;
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
        $prefixo .= (!($i % 5) && $i ? '-' : '').$chars[rand(0, $max)];
    }
    return $prefixo;
}

function serial(){
    $chars = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
    $serial = '';
    $max = count($chars)-1;
    for($i=0;$i<15;$i++){
        $serial .= (!($i % 5) && $i ? '-' : '').$chars[rand(0, $max)];
    }
    return $serial;
}
echo prefixo()."-".serial();
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você deva utilizar `random_bytes` ou `random_int` ao invés do `rand()`. A diferença é que o `random_*` vai utilizar o CSRPNG presente no sistema operacional, que é mais seguro do que LGC ou Mersenne Twister.

Você pode utilizar o `random_int` com o `pack`, da seguinte maneira:

```
function letra(int $limite) : string {
    $b = '';

    while(strlen($b) < $limite){
        $b .= pack('C', random_int(65, 90));
    }

    return $b;
}

function numero(int $limite) : string{
    return str_pad(
        random_int(0, str_repeat(9, $limite)),
        $limite, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo letra(5) . '-' . numero(5) . '-' . numero(5) . '-' . numero(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma [classe](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.php), exemplo:

> Classe *serial.class.php*

```
class Serial
{
  private $prefixo = "";
  public $letras = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
  public $numeros = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

  /* 
   * Método construtor
   * Cria um prefixo para cada objeto criado
   */
  public function __construct() {
    $max = count($this->letras)-1;
    for($a=0;$a<5;$a++) {
      $this->prefixo .= $this->letras[rand(0, $max)];
    }
    return $this;
  }

  /* 
   * Método get
   * Gera um serial de 15 digitos toda vez que o método for chamado
   */
  public function get() {
    $serial = '';
    $max = count($this->numeros)-1;
    for($b=0;$b<15;$b++){
      $serial .= (!($b % 5) && $b ? '-' : ''). $this->numeros[rand(0, $max)];
    }
    echo $this->prefixo."-".$serial."\n";
    return $this;
  }

}
```

> Como usar:

```
require_once('serial.class.php');

$serial_A = new Serial();
$serial_A->get()->get()->get()
         ->get()->get()->get()
         ->get()->get()->get()
         ->get()->get()->get()
         ->get()->get()->get()
         ->get()->get()->get();
```

> Exemplo de saída

```
MPRDM-68308-47678-09412
MPRDM-34567-47698-43685
MPRDM-79111-86573-68267
MPRDM-78570-58526-57259
MPRDM-89941-85110-50824
MPRDM-41477-69233-60018
MPRDM-76481-63231-98672
MPRDM-14028-03542-56162
MPRDM-41338-20932-00450
MPRDM-72468-49538-39004
MPRDM-82852-74510-92625
MPRDM-34866-98635-93850
MPRDM-42227-33041-72832
MPRDM-15014-94731-68651
MPRDM-12007-58515-50146
MPRDM-27148-78106-34490
MPRDM-99967-35102-51586
MPRDM-47226-20839-60614
```

> Podes ver funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/BurlywoodDarkgreyEmperorpenguin)